# Hide crash dialogs

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android kiosk application that shows different content in a cycle. From time to time, my app is killed due to internal exceptions in the WebView component. That issue is observed only on 4.4.2 version. Unfortunately this can't be caught by `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

I have spent a lot of time trying to find the cause, but seems that this bug is in chromium library observed on a few ROMs 4.4.2. As a solution I used `AlarmManager` to schedule my app restart each 10 seconds.

That works, but "Unfortunately app has been stopped" dialog appears above my app each time it's crashed for a few minutes. So is it possible to hide crash dialog after my app is restarted?

UPDATE: Guys, you requested me to provide the logs. Here it is

```
F/libc    ( 8052): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00760131 (code=1), thread 8177 (okit.lookplayer)
I/DEBUG   (18534): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (18534): Build fingerprint: 'rockchip/rk3188/rk3188:4.4.2/KOT49H/eng.root.20151104.193426:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (18534): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (18534): pid: 8052, tid: 8177, name: okit.lookplayer  >>> hk.lookit.lookplayer <<<
I/DEBUG   (18534): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00760131
I/DEBUG   (18534):     r0 a1bfd648  r1 a30cb1b0  r2 00760069  r3 00740063
I/DEBUG   (18534):     r4 a1bfd660  r5 9f6ea95c  r6 a1bfd8c8  r7 68eaae51
I/DEBUG   (18534):     r8 a491ecf0  r9 9f6ea95c  sl 00001181  fp 00001130
I/DEBUG   (18534):     ip 6968cf3c  sp 9f6ea920  lr 68eaae79  pc 68eaac9a  cpsr 00070030
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d4  c61c4c42c61fc10a  d5  55f8f60bfb98e3eb
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d6  8f62c856f6526eb9  d7  49037b5553094413
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d16 4040000000000000  d17 4040000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d18 9ab93edb31eaef77  d19 2043d21f22340145
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d20 3fc55335a3219dce  d21 bf66be2f9f628b11
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d22 bfc40e308f51834e  d23 4150000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d24 3f86bbd5ab753625  d25 bf86bbd51b36927f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d26 402de7ef44a49d17  d27 4000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d28 400140e308f51835  d29 3fc2230000000018
I/DEBUG   (18534):     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 414b773ffffffffa
I/DEBUG   (18534):     scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #00  pc 00ac6c9a  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #01  pc 00ac6e75  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #02  pc 00aab699  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #03  pc 00ac73b7  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #04  pc 00ac0f5d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #05  pc 00ac648d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #06  pc 002237bd  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #07  pc 00223977  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #08  pc 002239bf  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #09  pc 002225c5  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #10  pc 00225b45  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #11  pc 00225f11  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #12  pc 001e038b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #13  pc 001e0401  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #14  pc 001e7361  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #15  pc 001e018b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #16  pc 001cf4e5  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #17  pc 001d3feb  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #18  pc 001ced1f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #19  pc 008ecd79  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #20  pc 008ed12b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #21  pc 001dc3c9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #22  pc 001da203  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #23  pc 0000d228  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #24  pc 0000d3c0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): stack:
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8e0  00000080
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8e4  68e8f2d9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8e8  57aac93f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8ec  a1bfd8c8
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8f0  9f6ea95c
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8f4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8f8  68eaae51  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea8fc  a491ecf0
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea900  9f6ea95c
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea904  68e8f563  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea908  a1bfd8c8
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea90c  74726543
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea910  00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea914  a30cb1b0
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea918  9f6ea95c
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea91c  a1bfd8c8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #00  9f6ea920  a30cb1b0
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea924  68eaae79  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #01  9f6ea928  a3677448
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea92c  0000007b
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea930  000001ec
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea934  68e8f69b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):     #02  9f6ea938  00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea93c  693321a7  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea940  00000100
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea944  00001131
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea948  00001101
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea94c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea950  00001130
I/DEBUG   (18534):          9f6ea954  68eab3bb  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd628 00000005 0000001b 00000000 69331c79
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd638 00000000 00000000 00000000 000001cb
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd648 69658238 a1bfe510 a1bfe528 a1bfd978
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd658 a1bfd8c8 00000400 a38de8e8 a527ed10
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd668 00000001 00000e10 68608129 68607b6f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd678 00000000 00000504 00000000 000004ff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd688 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd698 00000000 00000000 0000037f 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6a8 0000005d 68606489 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6b8 00000000 68608451 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6c8 00000000 00000000 696577a0 696577a0
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6d8 69657968 00000000 a1bfb7f0 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6e8 a1bfe5d0 00000004 00000000 00019000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6f8 a1bfd810 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd708 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd718 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb190 a07faf60 9dbb6ea8 00000000 a05a92a0
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb1a0 00000000 a00abfd0 00000048 00000113
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb1b0 493d432f 3d4f2f4c 72617453 6d6f4374
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb1c0 64744c20 554f2f2e 6365533d 20657275
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb1d0 69676944 206c6174 74726543 63696669
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb1e0 20657461 6e676953 2f676e69 533d4e43
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb1f0 74726174 206d6f43 74726543 63696669
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb200 6f697461 7541206e 726f6874 00797469
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb210 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb220 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb230 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb240 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb250 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb260 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb270 00000000 00000000 00740063 00760069
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a30cb280 04340065 04370020 04320430 04400442
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760048 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760058 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760068 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760078 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760088 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760098 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007600a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007600b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007600c8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007600d8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007600e8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007600f8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760108 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760118 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760128 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00760138 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r3:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007400a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007400b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007400c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007400d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007400e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     007400f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740100 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740110 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740120 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00740130 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd640 00000000 000001cb 69658238 a1bfe510
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd650 a1bfe528 a1bfd978 a1bfd8c8 00000400
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd660 a38de8e8 a527ed10 00000001 00000e10
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd670 68608129 68607b6f 00000000 00000504
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd680 00000000 000004ff 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd690 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6a0 0000037f 00000000 0000005d 68606489
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 68608451
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6d0 696577a0 696577a0 69657968 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6e0 a1bfb7f0 00000000 a1bfe5d0 00000004
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd6f0 00000000 00019000 a1bfd810 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd700 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd710 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd720 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd730 00000000 00000000 a1bfe5a8 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea93c 693321a7 00000100 00001131 00001101
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea94c 00000000 00001130 68eab3bb a510ced8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea95c a1bfd648 57aac93f a1bfd8c8 00000003
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea96c a510ced8 00000003 68ea4f61 0000000f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea97c 00000000 00000000 57aac93f 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea98c a510ced8 a15474a8 401ce384 9f6ea9d4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea99c 00000000 401ce384 692ae6e2 6968ce54
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9ac 68eaa48f a510ced8 692ae6e2 9f6ea9e4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9bc 686077bf 68607799 685d114d a69c88ad
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9cc 0000004f 9f6ea9c0 693b15b2 692ae6e2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9dc 0000033e 68607799 693b15b2 692ae6e2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9ec 0000033e 68607799 00000000 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9fc 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6eaa0c 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6eaa1c 00000000 00000000 00000000 685b0000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6eaa2c f9227000 0000fa00 f921d600 0000fa00
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd8a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd8b8 00000000 00000000 00000001 0000006b
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd8c8 a3677448 68ea94ab 68ea944d 00000089
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd8d8 00000100 00000009 00000080 00000200
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd8e8 00000000 000000d9 00000081 00000004
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd8f8 00000000 00000000 00000218 000000b2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd908 00000175 00000000 0000009c 00000007
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd918 00000000 00000000 000003b0 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd928 00000000 0000002b 00000096 00000013
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd938 03c52b80 78656c66 6e6f632d 6c6f7274
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd948 7568742d 0073626d 00000028 00000023
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd958 0000001d 00000013 a0570ab8 00000040
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd968 695ea610 00000001 00000020 00000053
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd978 00000001 a1bfd9c8 a1bfd9f8 a1bfda28
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd988 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a1bfd998 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae30 4620faeb f7d221f4 4620fb03 e8bdb003
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae40 f7d24030 b003bae1 bf00bd30 00487415
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae50 4604b538 460d684b f8d0b133 f8d010ac
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae60 188820a8 dd144283 68a84621 fb72f7e4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae70 46216828 fef2f7ff f8c42301 68283094
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae80 b10a6ac2 47904621 e8bd4620 f7ff4038
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae90 bd38bf71 4604b5f8 4617460e 4a19b13a
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaea0 210c2009 23cdf240 f7d2447a 6920f8b3
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaeb0 f7e44631 42b0fbb1 d10a4605 69204631
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaec0 fb48f7e4 26014631 46204605 fec6f7ff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaed0 2600e000 4a0cb13f 210c200a 23d5f240
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaee0 f7d2447a b156f897 f8c52301 6ae23094
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaef0 4620b112 47904629 f7ff4628 4630ff3b
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf00 bf00bdf8 004872fb 004872c3 6c4ab121
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf10 2201b112 bfbef7ff 47702000 f44fb573
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf20 4e3e7322 460d4604 447e9300 00a4f101
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ecd0 c824e4ff 4773c0c6 07600e70 003b0004
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ece0 a32c0a40 a5ac0ea0 00000ab8 00000013
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ecf0 a30548a8 00000000 5def177b 0000002b
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed00 00000002 69b87cd8 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed10 a05ae060 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed20 00000028 00000519 a4d6b1d8 a3c67348
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000004
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed60 00000000 00000000 00000048 0000002a
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed70 695edff8 00000000 00000001 24191464
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed80 24156804 00000001 00000000 00725103
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491ed90 00000070 0000005a 00000000 00220000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491eda0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00220000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491edb0 00000000 7fffffc0 7fffffc0 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     a491edc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea93c 693321a7 00000100 00001131 00001101
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea94c 00000000 00001130 68eab3bb a510ced8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea95c a1bfd648 57aac93f a1bfd8c8 00000003
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea96c a510ced8 00000003 68ea4f61 0000000f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea97c 00000000 00000000 57aac93f 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea98c a510ced8 a15474a8 401ce384 9f6ea9d4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea99c 00000000 401ce384 692ae6e2 6968ce54
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9ac 68eaa48f a510ced8 692ae6e2 9f6ea9e4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9bc 686077bf 68607799 685d114d a69c88ad
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9cc 0000004f 9f6ea9c0 693b15b2 692ae6e2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9dc 0000033e 68607799 693b15b2 692ae6e2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9ec 0000033e 68607799 00000000 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9fc 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6eaa0c 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6eaa1c 00000000 00000000 00000000 685b0000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6eaa2c f9227000 0000fa00 f921d600 0000fa00
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001160 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001170 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001180 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001190 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001200 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001210 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001220 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001230 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001240 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001250 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001110 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001120 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001130 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001140 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001150 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001160 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001170 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001180 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001190 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     000011f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     00001200 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf1c 6834b5fd 405972bd 405186cd 4052a11b
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf2c 405186ef 40599d01 40599c49 4033d61b
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf3c 401ba710 401a04b0 40534a83 402e5550
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf4c 401ba80c 407498e9 40880071 4087c2c9
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf5c 4087c2d1 4087be95 40748ad9 40762099
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf6c 40760f65 408a4529 40760495 4075e4f9
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf7c 401ba730 40868399 40749e19 40749e09
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf8c 4076cc0d 401ab0d9 401a99b1 401a27a0
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cf9c 401ae3ab 401ab5c1 401adaed 401a0374
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cfac 40194501 401a0448 4033ec2d 40345367
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cfbc 4033ec73 403453fd 4033ef41 4033da2d
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cfcc 4033d937 4033d7a5 4033d90b 4019454d
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cfdc 401a602d 40194935 401a07a4 4034541d
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cfec 4018dcb9 4033d9b1 4033d8dd 401a5951
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968cffc 4018dca5 40341233 401a0c34 401a0c74
I/DEBUG   (18534):     6968d00c 401a0b94 401a0acc 401a0bb4 401949e1
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea900 9f6ea95c 68e8f563 a1bfd8c8 74726543
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea910 00000000 a30cb1b0 9f6ea95c a1bfd8c8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea920 a30cb1b0 68eaae79 a3677448 0000007b
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea930 000001ec 68e8f69b 00000000 693321a7
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea940 00000100 00001131 00001101 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea950 00001130 68eab3bb a510ced8 a1bfd648
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea960 57aac93f a1bfd8c8 00000003 a510ced8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea970 00000003 68ea4f61 0000000f 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea980 00000000 57aac93f 00000000 a510ced8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea990 a15474a8 401ce384 9f6ea9d4 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9a0 401ce384 692ae6e2 6968ce54 68eaa48f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9b0 a510ced8 692ae6e2 9f6ea9e4 686077bf
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9c0 68607799 685d114d a69c88ad 0000004f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9d0 9f6ea9c0 693b15b2 692ae6e2 0000033e
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9e0 68607799 693b15b2 692ae6e2 0000033e
I/DEBUG   (18534):     9f6ea9f0 68607799 00000000 ffffffff 00000000
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaac78 2300d103 61c36183 61c3e013 00c8f8d1
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaac88 42a3e00d 6182d105 00ccf8d1 30c8f8c0
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaac98 f8c2e007 f8d130c8 f8d100c8 f8c020cc
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaca8 220020cc 20ccf8c1 20c8f8c1 b5f8bd10
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaacb8 4607240a 4616460d 68314628 f83df7e8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaacc8 dc012800 bdf82000 46294638 f7fe6832
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaacd8 b110fbf7 d1ef3c01 2001e7f4 0000bdf8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaace8 20f4b537 22c04d20 4629447d faacf7d2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaacf8 b9404604 201421c3 22419100 462b21bd
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad08 f9c8f7e0 2100e02e f6ba22f4 2301cd88
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad18 7098f44f 30a0f8c4 30a4f8c4 f8c42500
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad28 200000a8 cffcf6ba 50c8f8c4 50ccf8c4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad38 f8c44621 f10450b0 f8c402c0 f8c450d0
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad48 f8c450d4 f8c450d8 f8c450dc f8c450e0
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad58 200300ac fde2f006 508cf8c4 5090f8c4
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaad68 50f0f8c4 bd3e4620 004874b3 4604b537
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae58 f8d0b133 f8d010ac 188820a8 dd144283
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae68 68a84621 fb72f7e4 46216828 fef2f7ff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae78 f8c42301 68283094 b10a6ac2 47904621
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae88 e8bd4620 f7ff4038 bd38bf71 4604b5f8
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaae98 4617460e 4a19b13a 210c2009 23cdf240
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaea8 f7d2447a 6920f8b3 f7e44631 42b0fbb1
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaeb8 d10a4605 69204631 fb48f7e4 26014631
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaec8 46204605 fec6f7ff 2600e000 4a0cb13f
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaed8 210c200a 23d5f240 f7d2447a b156f897
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaee8 f8c52301 6ae23094 4620b112 47904629
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaef8 f7ff4628 4630ff3b bf00bdf8 004872fb
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf08 004872c3 6c4ab121 2201b112 bfbef7ff
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf18 47702000 f44fb573 4e3e7322 460d4604
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf28 447e9300 00a4f101 2101220e f7d24633
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf38 4632f89f 210c2009 238bf240 f866f7d2
I/DEBUG   (18534):     68eaaf48 46296920 fa78f7e4 28004606 42a8d049
I/DEBUG   (18534):
I/DEBUG   (18534): memory map around fault addr 00760131:
I/DEBUG   (18534):     (no map below)
I/DEBUG   (18534):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   (18534):     20800000-20900000 rw-
I/BootReceiver(18841): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
D/Zygote  (18578): Process 8052 terminated by signal (11)
```

Comment: Whats the crush log all about?

Comment: As per logs there's an segmentation fault happened in the cromium library - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEVG). Trick is that it's not possible to handle such signals from the application side. System immediately kills the application's process. 
I've found many questions here related that and tried a lot of configuration of my WebView, but with no luck. Also I've spent many hours trying to find something specific to my case in the chromium bug tracker. It seems this bug has been fixed in further versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue in my application today only, It was happening with a Asus tab having android version 4.4.2 . Even I spend lot of time after it but all waste. Finally today i update android version of that **Asus Tab** now it is working fine. From some source i read that in android version 4.4.2 WebView doesnt works fine and it requires at least  android 4.4.4 and above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, seems that you understand that I feel :) 
I have devices with 4.4.4 onboard and WebView works as expected there. 
As alternative I've tried to integrate Crosswalk web component in my app. Original issue disappeared, but Crosswalk is also unstable on 4.4.2 - after approximately 2 hours of web page loading (I switch pages every 30 seconds) it become to leak memory that cause chromium crash as well.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you not to hide crash dialog, but to find and solve the reason.
Connect your device with android 4.4.2 and find crash log in your IDE.
Then past the log here if you need help with solving

Comment: You're right, better to fix the root cause of the problem. Unfortunately in my case it's not possible, due to crash happens in the 3rd party library.

Comment: You still at least can wrap into try catch the pice of code, which calls problem code from your library. Paste your ligcat with crash info

Comment: There's no synchronous call to the library that could be wrapped by try catch. Also there's no Java exception at all. App is killed by system due to SIGSEVG signal caused by 3rd party lib. There's nothing to do from Java side to prevent app death. 
3rd party library I mentioned is chromium. From KitKat release, Google replaced WebKit by chromium. So WebView uses chromium to do it's "web" stuff. 

I'll paste logcat output as soon as I get it again. But I'm sure there's no way to fix it from Java side.

Comment: So, I've added crash log.

Comment: Seems your app tries to access memory outside of it's memory space. So crash occurs in native code, but not in java. Is this complete crash report? I mean aren't there any additional traces at the end which can give you the clue?

Comment: There's no exceptions/errors before/after in the logs. SIGSEVG happens randomly when I load urls in WebView every 30 seconds. Sometimes it works for hours without the crash.

Anyways. Bug in chromium lib, I do believe there's no way to avoid it right now. That's why I just want to find a workaround to hide crash dialog for this particular case.

Answer (score -1):

You never hide the crash dialogs, is important tell to the user what happend, but you can customize, check [THIS](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/03/13/customize-force-close-dialog-android/)

Remmember, you can always use Android Monitor yo check the errors.

Comment: Remember, you can always read the question properly before posting an answer .
Link you mentioned describes how to use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. As I wrote in the question, that approach doesn't work for my case.